# Replace Static Content with Dynamic Featured Post Content on Home Page - Blogger Blogspot

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

I have html, css & js code for a website - I am more of a designer than a coder but so far I have managed to learn enough about sections & widgets within the Blogger platform to present my website as it was designed.

However my next goal is to replace my static content with dynamic content from my posts in blogger while maintaining the structure / layout of my original design.

I would like to achieve this via post data variables. This will allow me to reference the variables in any div tag. This also means that the css I already have, can be applied to the post image, and post title feeds.

If I had the data set from 4 featured posts and place each data set into 4 different variables post1, post2, post3, & post7.

I would then have my initial image url's and title's replaced with featured post images and titles. One of the variables might look something like -  post2.firstImageUrl - which I could place anywhere, in any order, in any of my div tags on my home page.

I have tried out code from various articles online but so far the data comes back in a bundle - which is less than ideal. Does anyone know what variables and supporting code will work in this scenario. Your efforts will be greatly appreciated.

The following link points to an article which is close, but not quite there. It might just need a little tweaking.

http://strapboot.blogspot.com/2014/12/show-recont-post-original-image-from.html

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>

  //<![CDATA[

function labelthumbs(json) {

    document.write('<ul id="label_with_thumbs">');
    for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];

        var posttitle = entry.title.$t;

        var posturl;
        if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'replies' && entry.link[k].type == 'text/html') {
                var commenttext = entry.link[k].title;
                var commenturl = entry.link[k].href;
            }

            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                posturl = entry.link[k].href;
                break;
            }
        }
        var thumburl;
        try {
            thumburl = entry.media$image.url;
        } catch (error)

        {
            s = entry.content.$t;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
            c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
                thumburl = d;
            } else thumburl = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zP87C2q9yog/UVopoHY30SI/AAAAAAAAE5k/AIyPvrpGLn8/s1600/picture_not_available.png';
        }

        var postdate = entry.published.$t;

        var cdyear = postdate.substring(0, 4);

        var cdmonth = postdate.substring(5, 7);

        var cdday = postdate.substring(8, 10);

        var monthnames = new Array();
        monthnames[1] = "Jan";
        monthnames[2] = "Feb";
        monthnames[3] = "Mar";
        monthnames[4] = "Apr";
        monthnames[5] = "May";
        monthnames[6] = "June";
        monthnames[7] = "July";
        monthnames[8] = "Aug";
        monthnames[9] = "Sept";
        monthnames[10] = "Oct";
        monthnames[11] = "Nov";
        monthnames[12] = "Dec";
        document.write('<li class="clearfix">');
        if (showpostthumbnails == true)

            document.write('<strong><a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top">' + posttitle + '</a></strong><br> <a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top"><img class="label_thumb" src="' + thumburl + '"/></a>');
        document.write('');
        if ("content" in entry) {
            var postcontent = entry.content.$t;
        } else

        if ("summary" in entry) {
            var postcontent = entry.summary.$t;
        } else var postcontent = "";
        var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
        postcontent = postcontent.replace(re, "");

        if (showpostsummary == true) {
            if (postcontent.length < numchars) {
                document.write('');
                document.write(postcontent);
                document.write('');
            } else {
                document.write('');
                postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, numchars);

                var quoteEnd = postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");
                postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, quoteEnd);
                document.write(postcontent + '...');
                document.write('');
            }
        }

        var towrite = '';
        var flag = 0;
        document.write('<br>');
        if (showpostdate == true) {
            towrite = towrite + monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth, 10)] + '-' + cdday + ' - ' + cdyear;
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (showcommentnum == true)

        {
            if (flag == 1) {
                towrite = towrite + ' | ';
            }

            if (commenttext == '1 Comments') commenttext = '1 Comment';
            if (commenttext == '0 Comments') commenttext = 'No Comments';
            commenttext = '<a href="' + commenturl + '" target ="_top">' + commenttext + '</a>';
            towrite = towrite + commenttext;
            flag = 1;;
        }

        if (displaymore == true)

        {
            if (flag == 1) towrite = towrite + ' | ';
            towrite = towrite + '<a href="' + posturl + '" class="url" target ="_top">More »</a>';
            flag = 1;;
        }

        document.write(towrite);
        document.write('</li>');
        if (displayseparator == true)

            if (i != (numposts - 1))

                document.write('');
    }
    document.write('</ul>');
}

  //]]>

</script>
```

I believe a solution of this nature will ensure that my template structure remains true to design, and means I can develop my site offline knowing that I can integrate into the blogger platform as efficiently as possible.